# If condition logic Not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if (!this.state.username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!outlook.com)(?!aol.com)(?!live.com)(?!hotmail.com)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) {
    alert("Only Business Emails Are Allowed");
} 

if (!this.state.phonenumber.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
    alert("10 digit mobile number or 10 digit Area code followed by landline number only allowed");       
} else {

    let data = Object.assign({
        profilePhoto: (this.state.files && this.state.files.length == "0") ? "" : this.state.files[0].base64,
    }, this.state);

    UserAction._createUser(data,  (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        (data.response == "SUCCESS") ? this.setState({ gotSuccess:true, openrejectDialog: true}) : alert(data.message)

    });

}
```

I am checking the condition based on match of username and phonenumber.
If username or phonenumber is not matched i am getting alert. and on click on "ok" from alert it is going to else 
I want else statement should be called after successfull completion of "if" conditions

Comment: May be the second `if` should be `else if`.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you are not doing it right, you should use if/else on each validation and the last case would be your successful call.

based on your code, if your username is wrong and the number is correct, you would call the `createUser` functionality and that is not the desired flow.

below you have a working code:

if the username is wrong, display error.

if the username is correct, check if the number is correct, if it is not, display error.

default case if all checks were passed.

```js
if (!this.state.username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!outlook.com)(?!aol.com)(?!live.com)(?!hotmail.com)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) {
  alert("Only Business Emails Are Allowed");

} else if (!this.state.phonenumber.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
  alert("10 digit mobile number or 10 digit Area code followed by landline number only allowed");

} else {

  let data = Object.assign({
    profilePhoto: this.state.files && this.state.files.length == "0" ? "" : this.state.files[0].base64,
  }, this.state);

  UserAction._createUser(data, (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    data.response == "SUCCESS" ? this.setState({
      gotSuccess: true,
      openrejectDialog: true
    }) : alert(data.message)

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re making the `else` code conditional only to the second `if` statement.

Shortly, the `else` code do not depends to the first `if`.

You could try this, to run the `else` only if both `if`’s are *false* :

```
if( <checks if the email is valid>){
    alert("Only Business Emails Are Allowed");
} else if ( <checks the phone number>){
    alert("10 digit mobile number or 10 digit Area code followed by landline number only allowed");
} else {
    /* the else code here */
}
```